# Kafka server / broker disk full - How to remove broker from cluster and reset Kafka storage?

Tags: apache-kafka

One of the brokers in a multi-broker Kafka cluster has filled its storage.

I want to purge all data which is stored in topics, and reset this broker, removing it from the existing cluster.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method appears to be:

- stop kafka with `systemctl`
- clear the log directory with `rm -r`
- re-create the broker id
- re-format the log directory
- start the broker

For the specific machine I am using the commands are:

- `systemctl stop kafka`
- `rm -r /opt/kafka/logs/kraft-combined-logs`
- `/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-storage.sh random-uuid`
- `/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-storage.sh format -t "<UUID>" -c /opt/kafka/config/kraft/server.properties`
- Note: I needed to modify `server.properties` to set this broker so that it thinks it is part of a single broker setup and is no longer linked to the existing brokers in the cluster.
- `systemctl start kafka`

The reason why I wanted to remove this broker from the cluster is that the root partition only has a small amount of space. (256GB)

The other brokers have much larger storage.

Essentially, I did this to turn this broker "off". I still want it running Kafka as having another machine running a seperate Kafka cluster is useful for testing purposes.